# UNITY iPhone game crashes after watching IronSource Ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, ironsource

I am using IronSource for ads. After showing 3-4 ads on iPhone, game crashes because memory increases fast (on iPhone 7 - got 1.3 GB of RAM, and then crashed).

error from xcode - UnityGfxDeviceWorker (32): signal SIGABRT

Answer (score 0):

When i was putting ads into my unity game i just used unity ads instead of IronSource, because unity ads are more easy to use

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pu_CpjBFtI